# QPropertyAnimation for QGraphics does not work

Tags: qt

So I have looked at other similar questions on stackoverflow but none seem to help. The problem is that the animation doesn't occur, but once I click somewhere in the QGraphicsView, it updates to the end position.

I'm animating QGraphicsRectItem with QPropertyAnimation, so I made a new class and extended QObject and QGraphicsRectItem:

```
class MyGraphicsRectItem : public QObject, public QGraphicsRectItem {
        Q_OBJECT
        Q_PROPERTY(QPointF position READ position WRITE setPosition)
        Q_PROPERTY(QRectF geometry READ geometry WRITE setGeometry)
    public:
        ...
        QPointF position();
        void setPosition(QPointF animBox);
        QRectF geometry();
        void setGeometry(QRectF geo);
        ...
}
```

One common problem with regarding this problem is that QPropertyAnimation goes out of scope when the function finishes, but I think I circumvented this problem using QAbstractAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped. In my MainWindow.cpp, I have:

```
group = new QParallelAnimationGroup;
for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; i += 1) {
    MyGraphicsRectItem *temp = dynamic_cast<MyGraphicsRectItem*>(histZToItem[i]);
    QPropertyAnimation *anim = new QPropertyAnimation(temp, "position");
    anim->setDuration(500);
    anim->setStartValue(temp->pos());
    QPropertyAnimation *geo = new QPropertyAnimation(temp, "geometry");
    geo->setDuration(500);
    geo->setStartValue(temp->rect());
    geo->setEndValue(QRectF(0, 0, colWidth, -80));
    if (i > anchorID) {
       anim->setEndValue(QPointF(40 + spaceWidth * (i) + colWidth * (i - 1), graphScene->height() - 40));
    } else {
       anim->setEndValue(QPointF(40 + spaceWidth * (i + 1) + colWidth * (i), graphScene->height() - 40));
    }
    group->addAnimation(geo);
    group->addAnimation(anim);
}
group->start(QAbstractAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);
```

Any ideas?

**Edit**
Here are my implementations for position, setPosition, geometry and setGeometry:

```
QPointF MyGraphicsRectItem::position()
{
    return QGraphicsRectItem::pos();
}

void MyGraphicsRectItem::setPosition(QPointF animPos)
{
     QGraphicsRectItem::setPos(animPos);
}

QRectF MyGraphicsRectItem::geometry()
{
    return rect();
}

void MyGraphicsRectItem::setGeometry(QRectF geo)
{
    setRect(geo);
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Here's the constructor:

```
MyGraphicsRectItem::MyGraphicsRectItem(qreal x, qreal y, qreal width, qreal height, QGraphicsItem *parent) :QGraphicsRectItem(x, y, width, height, parent) {
    setAcceptHoverEvents(true);
}
```

Comment: Do `setPosition`, `setGeometry` etc. all get called as and when you would expect?  Also, please show their implementations.

Comment: Edited! After I click the QGraphicsView, they all end up in the correct position with the correct geometry, it's just I don't see the actual animation until after I click. So I don't think they're getting called?

Comment: Also, something just occurred to me, it is possible to run an animation while another animation is occurring right? Before the snippet of code I showed in my mainwindow, I am animating qgraphicslineitems to fade out.  May that be the problem?

Comment: try changing `QGraphicsRectItem::setPos(animPos);` to `setPos(animPos);` and `return QGraphicsRectItem::pos();` to `return pos();`

Comment: You could share your complete code through github or similar

Comment: Unfortunately, changing those methods as you said doesn't change anything. I'd also prefer not to show my complete code. Any other ideas?

Comment: Could you show the MyGraphicsRectItem constructor?

Comment: You haven't answered my original question though -- do setPosition, setGeometry etc. all get called as and when you would expect?  Put some debug output statements in them that print the new position/geometry each time they are called.

Comment: Hi, I just added the constructor. I did add some debug output statements and a lot of data is printed out and it is slightly hard to sift through as there are 10 qrectitems. But it does look like they are updating as expected. I'll get back to you by adding an index to the print statement so I know which statements are which qrectitems.

Comment: @G.M. my debug statements do get called when the animation should start. The values of animPos and geometry are slightly changing every time the methods get called.
`0 QRectF(0,0 37.7534x0)
0 QPointF(68.3151,124)
...
0 QRectF(0,0 37.7534x0)
0 QPointF(68.3151,124)
...
0 QRectF(0,0 37.9935x-6.88)
0 QPointF(68.4952,124)
...
0 QRectF(0,0 40.5455x-80)
0 QPointF(70.4091,124)`

Comment: I have tried your code and I have not had any problems

Comment: change to constructor to : `MyGraphicsRectItem::MyGraphicsRectItem(QObject *parent):QObject(parent)
{

}`

Comment: `MyGraphicsRectItem(QObject *parent=0);` on .cpp

Comment: Just to clarify, you want me to create a new constructor, use that when I create MyGraphicsRectItems and set the parent to my mainWindow? I'm also getting an error that I can't convert QObject* to QGraphicsItem* because QGraphicsRectItem expects a QGraphicsItem*

Comment: I thought that was the problem, but I tried your constructor and it works for me, right now I'm uploading the link for my test so that you can test it.

Comment: see this: https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/ParallelAnimationGroup

Comment: Hi, so I looked at your github code, and almost everything is identical, the only thing that is different is this line: `MyGraphicsRectItem *temp = new MyGraphicsRectItem(0, 0, 100, 100);` I'm using a `std::map<int, QGraphicsItem*>` to get temp and then I'm dynamically casting to get a MyGraphicsRectItem, could that be a problem? Maybe it's looking in QGraphicsItem for the signal or something?